# Keras regression model does not fit 2 labels simulataneously

Tags: python, keras, regression

I am trying to use keras to do nonlinear regression. I have simulated 90000 datasets and labelled them with 2 parameters. My goal is to have a fully connected NN to estimate these two parameters after training. Currently, the model works well for fitting only one label. As a test, I have tried fitting each label independently and this works well, however when I want to fit both simultaneously it fails (i.e., the model predicts 1 label accurately, but not the other. In some instances the second label is off by a factor of 1000 and in other cases it simply reads [0.] ... depending on the activation for my output layer). 1 label is on the order of 1e7 and the other label varies between 0 and 1. I have tried normalizing both labels to lie between 0 and 1 - this didn't help. Each input should be a vector of size 1024 and associated with 2 labels.

Any help or literature suggestions on how to fit multi-labelled data would be much appreciated. Attached below is the code for my model. Thank you.

```
# Build The Model
model = Sequential()

# The Input Layer :
    model.add(Dense(1024, kernel_initializer='normal', input_dim=1024, activation='relu'))

# The Hidden Layers :
    model.add(Dense(1024, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1024, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1024, kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))

# The Output Layer :
    model.add(Dense(2, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))

# Compile the network :
    model.compile(loss='MSE', optimizer='adam', metrics=['MSE'])
    model.summary()
```

Comment: Your last layer has relu activation. That means your model cannot predict negative values. Is that by design?

Comment: Yes - both labels are positive. I guess another question I have is that I know a priori that 1 label is constrained to lay between 0 and 1 - is there any way i can supply this to the model.

Comment: Usually, for regression you don't need any activation function on the last layer. However, if you know your labels are always between 0 and 1, `sigmoid` may be worth a try. But I've never used that for regression, so I cannot do a qualified comment on that.

Comment: you have to define a custom loss function to minimize, MSE expects one label and predicted value